# How to configure abp multi tenancy with domain tenant resolver?

Tags: multi-tenant, abp

I have set up the multi-tenancy configurations for my project by following the abp documentation here https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy. But the configurations do not work and the tenant is not identified. The current tenant id is always null.

I have added the following to my code:

- Enabled multi-tenancy and added the required packages and their dependencies.

```
    Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
    {
     options.IsEnabled = true;
    });
```

- Implemented IMultiTenant interface for all entities

```
    public class Group : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant
     {
      public Guid? TenantId {get; private set;}
      public string GroupName {get; private set;}
     }
```

- Added domain tenant resolver configuration

```
    services.Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
    {
     options.AddDomainTenantResolver("{0}.mydomain.net");
    });
```

- Added multi-tenancy middleware `app.UseMultiTenancy();`
- Created the tenant in the database and defined tenant in the appsettings.json as:

```
`   "Tenants": [
     {
      "Id": "922ff4a1-b518-dfb9-c6c4-3a08d587ddd1",
      "Name": "my-app-099d95303.2"
     }
     ]`
```

When a new user is registered using the angular app, the tenant is not resolved and the tenant id for the user is null. Same happens when any other entity object is created. Not sure what I am missing here.
What I want is that every entity gets its tenant Id so that if there are multiple instances of the angular app, the database query results can be filtered on the basis of that tenant id.

Comment: Yes. But i used a different approach. Instead of resolving the tenant through the domain tenant resolver, I added the tenant Id in the header of the incoming API request. In the configurations I used :            services.Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.TenantKey = "_tenant";
            });

Answer (score 0):

Did you inherit from `AsyncCrudAppService`?

```
protected override void TryToSetTenantId(TEntity entity)
        {
            var tenantId = CurrentTenant.Id;

            if (!tenantId.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            var propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(IMultiTenant.TenantId));

            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, tenantId, null);
            }
        }
```

I think [this](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1360) should solve your problem.

Comment: This did not work. I also tried using ITenantResolver and the ICurrentTenant dependency injections to get tenant id, but it is still null.

Comment: May I know the version of your current project?

Comment: the version is 6.0